# How to add a virtual layer using ST_ClusterDBSCAN function

Tags: qgis, clustering, virtual-layer

I have a 'POINTS' layer with 74 points geometry with the fields "NAME" and "ID". I want to add a virtual layer with the following query to calculate the clusters using the DBSCAN function:

```
SELECT NAME, ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geometry, 4, 2, ID) over() AS cluster_id, *
FROM POINTS
```

The result I get is an error message as shown in the screenshot:
[image]

What could I do to get this error solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Virtual layers` use `SpatiaLite` under the hood, which doesn't have `st_clusterDBScan`. Instead, you can add a `query layer` using the `DB Manager`, which will forward the query to the database.

[image]